# Beautifying the output of Matlab aka human-readable form for output?

Tags: matlab, math, output, symbolic-math

```
syms x y z;
solve(x==y+1, y^2==z,z==9) 

ans = 

x: [2x1 sym] 
y: [2x1 sym] 
z: [2x1 sym]
```

and now I want to see the results like Mathematica outputting `{{x->-2,y->-3,z->9},{x->4,y->3,z->9}}` for `Solve[{x == y + 1, y^2 == z, z == 9}, {x, y, z}]`. The workspace window and then variable editor shows me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYZeC.png) but I still cannot see the real values stored there.

**How can I see the output of Matlab in human-readable form aka beautified form?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) states:

> When solving a system of equations, use one output argument to return the solutions in the form of a structure array

The result is returned as a struct, so you can access each field to see its value. The documentation brings an example of how to do it:

```
S = solve(x==y+1, y^2==z, z==9);
[S.x, S.y, S.z]
```

This should result in:

```
ans =
     4     3     9
    -2    -3     9
```

Alternatively, you can return the solutions in separate variables by specifying multiple output arguments:

```
[solx, soly, solz] = solve(x==y+1, y^2==z, z==9)
```

and this will result in:

```
solx =
     4
    -2

soly =
     3
    -3

solz =
     9
    -9
```

Comment: Thank you, somehow skipped the part in manual -- luckily getting now more in-depth answers than even in manual :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not straightforward to view the contents of a struct type in MATLAB. One quick approach is to do something like this:

```
r=struct2cell(solve(x==y+1, y^2==z,z==9));
r{:}

ans =

  4
 -2


ans =

  3
 -3


ans =

 9
 9
```

If you want to identify the actual variable names, I think you'll need to write a custom routine to print them how you'd like them to appear.

Comment: Interesting, a way not mentioned in manuals -- perhaps becocing useful in the future but the other method looks simpler to use anyway +1 for good try.